How can I efficiently `fill_null` only certain columns of a DataFrame?
For example, let us say I want to fill_null(strategy="zero") only the numeric columns of my DataFrame. My current strategy is to do this:
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("id", ["alpha", None, "gamma"]),
        pl.Series("xs", [None, 100, 2]),
    ]
)

final_df = df.select(cs.exclude(cs.numeric()))
final_df = final_df.with_columns(
    df.select(cs.numeric()).fill_null(strategy="zero")
)

print(final_df)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ id    ┆ xs  │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ alpha ┆ 0   │
│ null  ┆ 100 │
│ gamma ┆ 2   │
└───────┴─────┘

Are there alternative, either more idiomatic or more efficient methods to achieve what I'd like to do?

@roganjosh I missed an import. I am using polars.selectors: https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/selectors.html

@roganjosh I create final_df from df, by excluding numeric columns. df remains unchanged. Then, from df, I select only the numeric columns, and then fill null values in this reduced df. Finally, I re-add the columns of this reduced-df back into final_df.
Are you new to Polars? This is super standard stuff: to the point where I am likely being far too naive.

df.with_columns(cs.numeric().fill_null(strategy="zero").name.keep()) feels like it should work? I don't know how excluding numeric columns should result in them getting filled.

You can simply use: final_df = df.with_columns(df.select(cs.numeric()).fill_null(strategy = 'zero'))

You should provide a full runnable example along with the expected output to make it easier for people to see the exact problem. It's just: df.with_columns(cs.numeric().fill_null(strategy="zero")) - you do not need to filter out non-matching columns first in a separate select and rebuild a result.

@jqurious Done.

pl.DataFrame.select returns a dataframe that contains only the columns listed as arguments. Alternatively, pl.DataFrame.with_columns adds columns to the dataframe (and replaces columns with the same name).
Especially, this provides you with the tools to perform the filling without an intermediate dataframe. You can simply use pl.DataFrame.with_columns to fill missing values only in numeric columns (i.e. replace them with their filled versions).
df.with_columns(
    cs.numeric().fill_null(strategy="zero")
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ id    ┆ xs  │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ alpha ┆ 0   │
│ null  ┆ 100 │
│ gamma ┆ 2   │
└───────┴─────┘


Note that pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES is deprecated and cs.numeric() is the preferred method for selecting by dtype.

@BallpointBen Good catch. I've edited the question accordingly.
